# jQuery element not being removed after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I've created a jQuery function which animates an 'Add To Cart' button when clicked so it flies up to the cart icon on the top bar. I've cloned the div tag because I still want the Add To Cart button to be available after a user has clicked it once, and I have then set the animate function to remove the div which has flown upwards once completed.

My problem is that once the function has been run once, it will not run again. For example, if a customer clicks on the add to cart button, and then decides to click the button again, the button will not be animated on the second time.

Here's my JavaScript code - It may look a little too over-complicated but that's due to the positioning of the buttons on the page I'm working on.

```
$('.addToCart').click(function(){

    var leftPos = $(this).position().left + $(this).parent().offset().left;
    var existingLeftCSS = $(this).css('margin-left');
    var existingTopCSS = $(this).css('margin-top');
    var leftPos = parseFloat(leftPos) - parseFloat(existingLeftCSS);
    var topPos = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()+'px';
    var topPos = parseFloat(topPos) - parseFloat(existingTopCSS);
    var newLeftPos = $('#cartButton').offset().left - parseInt($(this).css('margin-left'));

    setTimeout(function(){$(this).remove();}, 110);
    $(this).clone().appendTo($(this).parent());
    $(this).css('z-index','999');


  $(this)
  .css({
      position:'fixed',
      top: topPos,
      left: leftPos
  })
  .animate({
    top:"40",
    left: newLeftPos

  }, 500, function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });


});
```

or for a simplified version of my problem, see this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jxbbm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace $(this).clone()... for

```
var clone = $(this).clone(); 
    $(clone).appendTo($(this).parent()); 
    $(clone).css('z-index','999'); 
    $(clone).css({
              position:'fixed',
              top: topPos,
              left: leftPos   })
    .animate({
            top:"8",
            left: newLeftPos   
    }, 500, function(){
              $(this).remove();   
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use event delegetion, as so:

```
$('.productBox').on('click', '.addToCart', function() {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change the first line of your code to

```
$('.productBox').on('click', '.addToCart', function(){
```